# Pass List<Double> value from one activity to other

Tags: android, list

I have a list like this,

```
List< Double> list_r = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

How can I pass this list from one activity to other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I pass this list from one activity to other ?

Then Make this list Static just like this:

```
public static List< Double> list_r = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

And Access this list in other activity like this:

```
private List<Double> list_my = ClassName.list_r;
```

Where ClassName is your Activity which consists (List< Double> list_r).

But make sure I am just showing a way of passing list. But by making List *static* It will consume memory even after you have finish the use of that arrayList.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `double[]` together with `putExtra(String, double[])` and `getDoubleArrayExtra(String)`.

Or you can use an `ArrayList<Double>` together with `putExtra(String, Serializable)` and `getSerializableExtra(String)` (the `ArrayList` part is important as it is `Serializable`, but the `List` interface is not).

Answer (score 0):

use **intent.putExtra();**

```
intent.putExtra("array_list", list_r );
```

Comment: `List< Double>` type is double not string and list does not implement serializable

Comment: @Raghunandan then how can i make it . please tell

Comment: @aav follow the link provided under your question instead of list use arraylist

Answer (score 0):

You may use of bundle how to use: [creating bundle and sending over to new activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9306197/creating-bundle-and-sending-over-to-new-activity) or save arrayList in shared preferences: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html

Answer (score 0):

```
intent.putExtra("list",list_r);
```

now on the other activity in onCreate:

```
getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("list");
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html. List does not implement serializable

Answer (score 0):

Convert double to string, and put it in ArrayList.
In the Activity providing the data, use Intent#putExtra():

```
double double1 = 0.05;
double double2 = 0.02;
ArrayList <String []> list = new ArrayList <String[]>();
list.add (new String [] {String.valueOf(double_1),String.valueOf(double_2)});
Intent i = new Intent (this,YourTargetActivity.class);
i.putExtra("list", list);
startActivity(i);
```

Then to retrieve, use Intent#getSerializableExtra() and cast to ArrayList  :

```
ArrayList <String[]> list = (ArrayList<String[]>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("list");
double double1 = Double.parseDouble(list.get(0)[0]) ;
double double1 = Double.parseDouble(list.get(0)[1]) ;
```

Comment: vow, i think this is the hardest way that can do. above answer much easier than this.